# SqlDependency - How do I interpret the SqlNotificationEventArgs properties?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sqldependency

I'm using the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(VS.90).aspx) class and have been trying unsuccessfully to find a list of possible combinations of the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.type(VS.90).aspx), [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.source(VS.90).aspx) and [Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.info(VS.90).aspx) properties of the [SqlNotificationEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs(VS.90).aspx) object.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189308.aspx) is the closest I've found so far.  However, I know this doesn't cover everything because I've already seen the combination Change/Client/Error.

I'd really like to know if I'm handling all possible cases in the best possible way.  That is, whenever possible I'd like to reestablish the "subscription". 
 For instance the  Change/Client/Error was do to a network issue that interrupted communication between SqlServer and my app.  Once communication was reestablished I was able to recover successfully.

### EDIT:

Maybe it would help if I gave some examples of the concerns I have.
For the following questions when I say "recover" I mean reestablish a subscription at runtime, that is without manual intervention.

- Is it safe to assume that a [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.type(VS.90).aspx) of `Subscribe` means there is nothing I can do to recover.
- Is it safe to assume that a [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.source(VS.90).aspx) of `Data` will always have a [Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.info(VS.90).aspx) of `truncate`, `insert`, `update`, or `delete`.  If not will it always be something similar.  I don't currently distinguish between these cases and I just reestablish the subscription and fetch the updated data.
- Is it safe to assume that, with the possible exception of an [Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.info(VS.90).aspx) of `Alter`, a [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs.source(VS.90).aspx) of `object` means that my query is no longer valid and I won't be able to recover.

Comment: A bit off topic, but when you say you recover from Client/Error, do you call SqlDependency.Stop/Start before recreating the dependency?

Comment: @Michał, I didn't need to call SqlDependency.Stop/Start to get the dependency working again.

Comment: ok, thanks. There's not a lot of verified info on this subject :/

Comment: When I was looking into SqlDependency I remember finding more enum values than Microsoft had documented. I got the impression MS had got about 90% of the implementation done then given up on the whole thing.

Comment: You can use .NET Reference source, and navigate/crossref back from SqlNotificationEventArgs ctor: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlNotificationEventArgs.cs,62cf5052ebde04a7,references. However, I've done that and found Subscribe/AlreadyChanged/Client, Subscribe/Error/Object, Change/Error/Timeout, and ... an internal SqlNotification class in the end that seems to accept anything from the wire...

Answer (score 10):

**Type** can be any of: Change, Subscribe, or Unknown

**Change**  Data on the server being monitored changed. Use the SqlNotificationInfo item to determine the details of the change.

**Subscribe** There was a failure to create a notification subscription. Use the SqlNotificationEventArgs object's SqlNotificationInfo item to determine the cause of the failure.

**Unknown** Used when the type option sent by the server was not recognized by the client.

```
  public enum SqlNotificationType {
        Change      = 0,
        Subscribe   = 1,

        // use negative values for client-only-generated values
        Unknown     = -1
    }
```

**Source** can be any of: Data, Timeout, Object, Database, System, Statement, Environment, Execution, Owner, Unknown, or Client

**Data** Data has changed; for example, an insert, update, delete, or truncate operation occurred.

**Timeout** The subscription time-out expired.

**Object** A database object changed; for example, an underlying object related to the query was dropped or modified.

**Database** The database state changed; for example, the database related to the query was dropped or detached.

**System** A system-related event occurred. For example, there was an internal error, the server was restarted, or resource pressure caused the invalidation.

**Statement** The Transact-SQL statement is not valid for notifications; for example, a SELECT statement that could not be notified or a non-SELECT statement was executed.

**Environment** The run-time environment was not compatible with notifications; for example, the isolation level was set to snapshot, or one or more SET options are not compatible.

**Execution** A run-time error occurred during execution.

**Owner** Internal only; not intended to be used in your code.

**Unknown** Used when the source option sent by the server was not recognized by the client.

**Client** A client-initiated notification occurred, such as a client-side time-out or as a result of attempting to add a command to a dependency that has already fired.

```
public enum SqlNotificationSource {
    Data        = 0,
    Timeout     = 1,
    Object      = 2,
    Database    = 3,
    System      = 4,
    Statement   = 5,
    Environment = 6,
    Execution   = 7,
    Owner       = 8,

    // use negative values for client-only-generated values
    Unknown     = -1,
    Client      = -2
}
```

**Info** can be any of: Truncate, Insert, Update, Delete, Drop, Alter, Restart, Error, Query, Invalid, Options, Isolation, Expired, Resource, PreviousFire, TemplateLimit, Merge, Unknown, or AlreadyChanged

**Truncate** One or more tables were truncated.

**Insert** Data was changed by an INSERT statement.

**Update** Data was changed by an UPDATE statement.

**Delete** Data was changed by a DELETE statement.

**Drop** An underlying object related to the query was dropped.

**Alter** An underlying server object related to the query was modified.

**Restart** The server was restarted (notifications are sent during restart.).

**Error** An internal server error occurred.

**Query** A SELECT statement that cannot be notified or was provided.

**Invalid** A statement was provided that cannot be notified (for example, an UPDATE statement).

**Options** The SET options were not set appropriately at subscription time.

**Isolation** The statement was executed under an isolation mode that was not valid (for example, Snapshot).

**Expired** The SqlDependency object has expired.

**Resource** Fires as a result of server resource pressure.

**PreviousFire** A previous statement has caused query notifications to fire under the current transaction.

**TemplateLimit** The subscribing query causes the number of templates on one of the target tables to exceed the maximum allowable limit.

**Unknown** Used when the info option sent by the server was not recognized by the client.

**AlreadyChanged** The SqlDependency object already fired, and new commands cannot be added to it.

**Merge** Used to distinguish the server-side cause for a query notification firing.

```
public enum SqlNotificationInfo {
        Truncate      = 0,
        Insert        = 1,
        Update        = 2,
        Delete        = 3,
        Drop          = 4,
        Alter         = 5,
        Restart       = 6,
        Error         = 7,
        Query         = 8,
        Invalid       = 9,
        Options       = 10,
        Isolation     = 11,
        Expired       = 12,
        Resource      = 13,
        PreviousFire  = 14,
        TemplateLimit = 15,
        Merge         = 16,

        // use negative values for client-only-generated values
        Unknown        = -1,
        AlreadyChanged = -2
    }
```

And finally, in answer to your question a list of possible combinations:

```
(Change, Data, Truncate), (Change, Data, Insert), (Change, Data, Update), (Change, Data, Delete), (Change, Data, Drop), (Change, Data, Alter), (Change, Data, Restart), (Change, Data, Error), (Change, Data, Query), (Change, Data, Invalid), (Change, Data, Options), (Change, Data, Isolation), (Change, Data, Expired), (Change, Data, Resource), (Change, Data, PreviousFire), (Change, Data, TemplateLimit), (Change, Data, Merge), (Change, Data, Unknown), (Change, Data, AlreadyChanged), (Change, Timeout, Truncate), (Change, Timeout, Insert), (Change, Timeout, Update), (Change, Timeout, Delete), (Change, Timeout, Drop), (Change, Timeout, Alter), (Change, Timeout, Restart), (Change, Timeout, Error), (Change, Timeout, Query), (Change, Timeout, Invalid), (Change, Timeout, Options), (Change, Timeout, Isolation), (Change, Timeout, Expired), (Change, Timeout, Resource), (Change, Timeout, PreviousFire), (Change, Timeout, TemplateLimit), (Change, Timeout, Merge), (Change, Timeout, Unknown), (Change, Timeout, AlreadyChanged), (Change, Object, Truncate), (Change, Object, Insert), (Change, Object, Update), (Change, Object, Delete), (Change, Object, Drop), (Change, Object, Alter), (Change, Object, Restart), (Change, Object, Error), (Change, Object, Query), (Change, Object, Invalid), (Change, Object, Options), (Change, Object, Isolation), (Change, Object, Expired), (Change, Object, Resource), (Change, Object, PreviousFire), (Change, Object, TemplateLimit), (Change, Object, Merge), (Change, Object, Unknown), (Change, Object, AlreadyChanged), (Change, Database, Truncate), (Change, Database, Insert), (Change, Database, Update), (Change, Database, Delete), (Change, Database, Drop), (Change, Database, Alter), (Change, Database, Restart), (Change, Database, Error), (Change, Database, Query), (Change, Database, Invalid), (Change, Database, Options), (Change, Database, Isolation), (Change, Database, Expired), (Change, Database, Resource), (Change, Database, PreviousFire), (Change, Database, TemplateLimit), (Change, Database, Merge), (Change, Database, Unknown), (Change, Database, AlreadyChanged), (Change, System, Truncate), (Change, System, Insert), (Change, System, Update), (Change, System, Delete), (Change, System, Drop), (Change, System, Alter), (Change, System, Restart), (Change, System, Error), (Change, System, Query), (Change, System, Invalid), (Change, System, Options), (Change, System, Isolation), (Change, System, Expired), (Change, System, Resource), (Change, System, PreviousFire), (Change, System, TemplateLimit), (Change, System, Merge), (Change, System, Unknown), (Change, System, AlreadyChanged), (Change, Statement, Truncate), (Change, Statement, Insert), (Change, Statement, Update), (Change, Statement, Delete), (Change, Statement, Drop), (Change, Statement, Alter), (Change, Statement, Restart), (Change, Statement, Error), (Change, Statement, Query), (Change, Statement, Invalid), (Change, Statement, Options), (Change, Statement, Isolation), (Change, Statement, Expired), (Change, Statement, Resource), (Change, Statement, PreviousFire), (Change, Statement, TemplateLimit), (Change, Statement, Merge), (Change, Statement, Unknown), (Change, Statement, AlreadyChanged), (Change, Environment, Truncate), (Change, Environment, Insert), (Change, Environment, Update), (Change, Environment, Delete), (Change, Environment, Drop), (Change, Environment, Alter), (Change, Environment, Restart), (Change, Environment, Error), (Change, Environment, Query), (Change, Environment, Invalid), (Change, Environment, Options), (Change, Environment, Isolation), (Change, Environment, Expired), (Change, Environment, Resource), (Change, Environment, PreviousFire), (Change, Environment, TemplateLimit), (Change, Environment, Merge), (Change, Environment, Unknown), (Change, Environment, AlreadyChanged), (Change, Execution, Truncate), (Change, Execution, Insert), (Change, Execution, Update), (Change, Execution, Delete), (Change, Execution, Drop), (Change, Execution, Alter), (Change, Execution, Restart), (Change, Execution, Error), (Change, Execution, Query), (Change, Execution, Invalid), (Change, Execution, Options), (Change, Execution, Isolation), (Change, Execution, Expired), (Change, Execution, Resource), (Change, Execution, PreviousFire), (Change, Execution, TemplateLimit), (Change, Execution, Merge), (Change, Execution, Unknown), (Change, Execution, AlreadyChanged), (Change, Owner, Truncate), (Change, Owner, Insert), (Change, Owner, Update), (Change, Owner, Delete), (Change, Owner, Drop), (Change, Owner, Alter), (Change, Owner, Restart), (Change, Owner, Error), (Change, Owner, Query), (Change, Owner, Invalid), (Change, Owner, Options), (Change, Owner, Isolation), (Change, Owner, Expired), (Change, Owner, Resource), (Change, Owner, PreviousFire), (Change, Owner, TemplateLimit), (Change, Owner, Merge), (Change, Owner, Unknown), (Change, Owner, AlreadyChanged), (Change, Unknown, Truncate), (Change, Unknown, Insert), (Change, Unknown, Update), (Change, Unknown, Delete), (Change, Unknown, Drop), (Change, Unknown, Alter), (Change, Unknown, Restart), (Change, Unknown, Error), (Change, Unknown, Query), (Change, Unknown, Invalid), (Change, Unknown, Options), (Change, Unknown, Isolation), (Change, Unknown, Expired), (Change, Unknown, Resource), (Change, Unknown, PreviousFire), (Change, Unknown, TemplateLimit), (Change, Unknown, Merge), (Change, Unknown, Unknown), (Change, Unknown, AlreadyChanged), (Change, Client, Truncate), (Change, Client, Insert), (Change, Client, Update), (Change, Client, Delete), (Change, Client, Drop), (Change, Client, Alter), (Change, Client, Restart), (Change, Client, Error), (Change, Client, Query), (Change, Client, Invalid), (Change, Client, Options), (Change, Client, Isolation), (Change, Client, Expired), (Change, Client, Resource), (Change, Client, PreviousFire), (Change, Client, TemplateLimit), (Change, Client, Merge), (Change, Client, Unknown), (Change, Client, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Data, Truncate), (Subscribe, Data, Insert), (Subscribe, Data, Update), (Subscribe, Data, Delete), (Subscribe, Data, Drop), (Subscribe, Data, Alter), (Subscribe, Data, Restart), (Subscribe, Data, Error), (Subscribe, Data, Query), (Subscribe, Data, Invalid), (Subscribe, Data, Options), (Subscribe, Data, Isolation), (Subscribe, Data, Expired), (Subscribe, Data, Resource), (Subscribe, Data, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Data, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Data, Merge), (Subscribe, Data, Unknown), (Subscribe, Data, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Timeout, Truncate), (Subscribe, Timeout, Insert), (Subscribe, Timeout, Update), (Subscribe, Timeout, Delete), (Subscribe, Timeout, Drop), (Subscribe, Timeout, Alter), (Subscribe, Timeout, Restart), (Subscribe, Timeout, Error), (Subscribe, Timeout, Query), (Subscribe, Timeout, Invalid), (Subscribe, Timeout, Options), (Subscribe, Timeout, Isolation), (Subscribe, Timeout, Expired), (Subscribe, Timeout, Resource), (Subscribe, Timeout, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Timeout, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Timeout, Merge), (Subscribe, Timeout, Unknown), (Subscribe, Timeout, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Object, Truncate), (Subscribe, Object, Insert), (Subscribe, Object, Update), (Subscribe, Object, Delete), (Subscribe, Object, Drop), (Subscribe, Object, Alter), (Subscribe, Object, Restart), (Subscribe, Object, Error), (Subscribe, Object, Query), (Subscribe, Object, Invalid), (Subscribe, Object, Options), (Subscribe, Object, Isolation), (Subscribe, Object, Expired), (Subscribe, Object, Resource), (Subscribe, Object, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Object, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Object, Merge), (Subscribe, Object, Unknown), (Subscribe, Object, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Database, Truncate), (Subscribe, Database, Insert), (Subscribe, Database, Update), (Subscribe, Database, Delete), (Subscribe, Database, Drop), (Subscribe, Database, Alter), (Subscribe, Database, Restart), (Subscribe, Database, Error), (Subscribe, Database, Query), (Subscribe, Database, Invalid), (Subscribe, Database, Options), (Subscribe, Database, Isolation), (Subscribe, Database, Expired), (Subscribe, Database, Resource), (Subscribe, Database, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Database, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Database, Merge), (Subscribe, Database, Unknown), (Subscribe, Database, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, System, Truncate), (Subscribe, System, Insert), (Subscribe, System, Update), (Subscribe, System, Delete), (Subscribe, System, Drop), (Subscribe, System, Alter), (Subscribe, System, Restart), (Subscribe, System, Error), (Subscribe, System, Query), (Subscribe, System, Invalid), (Subscribe, System, Options), (Subscribe, System, Isolation), (Subscribe, System, Expired), (Subscribe, System, Resource), (Subscribe, System, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, System, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, System, Merge), (Subscribe, System, Unknown), (Subscribe, System, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Statement, Truncate), (Subscribe, Statement, Insert), (Subscribe, Statement, Update), (Subscribe, Statement, Delete), (Subscribe, Statement, Drop), (Subscribe, Statement, Alter), (Subscribe, Statement, Restart), (Subscribe, Statement, Error), (Subscribe, Statement, Query), (Subscribe, Statement, Invalid), (Subscribe, Statement, Options), (Subscribe, Statement, Isolation), (Subscribe, Statement, Expired), (Subscribe, Statement, Resource), (Subscribe, Statement, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Statement, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Statement, Merge), (Subscribe, Statement, Unknown), (Subscribe, Statement, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Environment, Truncate), (Subscribe, Environment, Insert), (Subscribe, Environment, Update), (Subscribe, Environment, Delete), (Subscribe, Environment, Drop), (Subscribe, Environment, Alter), (Subscribe, Environment, Restart), (Subscribe, Environment, Error), (Subscribe, Environment, Query), (Subscribe, Environment, Invalid), (Subscribe, Environment, Options), (Subscribe, Environment, Isolation), (Subscribe, Environment, Expired), (Subscribe, Environment, Resource), (Subscribe, Environment, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Environment, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Environment, Merge), (Subscribe, Environment, Unknown), (Subscribe, Environment, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Execution, Truncate), (Subscribe, Execution, Insert), (Subscribe, Execution, Update), (Subscribe, Execution, Delete), (Subscribe, Execution, Drop), (Subscribe, Execution, Alter), (Subscribe, Execution, Restart), (Subscribe, Execution, Error), (Subscribe, Execution, Query), (Subscribe, Execution, Invalid), (Subscribe, Execution, Options), (Subscribe, Execution, Isolation), (Subscribe, Execution, Expired), (Subscribe, Execution, Resource), (Subscribe, Execution, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Execution, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Execution, Merge), (Subscribe, Execution, Unknown), (Subscribe, Execution, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Owner, Truncate), (Subscribe, Owner, Insert), (Subscribe, Owner, Update), (Subscribe, Owner, Delete), (Subscribe, Owner, Drop), (Subscribe, Owner, Alter), (Subscribe, Owner, Restart), (Subscribe, Owner, Error), (Subscribe, Owner, Query), (Subscribe, Owner, Invalid), (Subscribe, Owner, Options), (Subscribe, Owner, Isolation), (Subscribe, Owner, Expired), (Subscribe, Owner, Resource), (Subscribe, Owner, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Owner, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Owner, Merge), (Subscribe, Owner, Unknown), (Subscribe, Owner, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Unknown, Truncate), (Subscribe, Unknown, Insert), (Subscribe, Unknown, Update), (Subscribe, Unknown, Delete), (Subscribe, Unknown, Drop), (Subscribe, Unknown, Alter), (Subscribe, Unknown, Restart), (Subscribe, Unknown, Error), (Subscribe, Unknown, Query), (Subscribe, Unknown, Invalid), (Subscribe, Unknown, Options), (Subscribe, Unknown, Isolation), (Subscribe, Unknown, Expired), (Subscribe, Unknown, Resource), (Subscribe, Unknown, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Unknown, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Unknown, Merge), (Subscribe, Unknown, Unknown), (Subscribe, Unknown, AlreadyChanged), (Subscribe, Client, Truncate), (Subscribe, Client, Insert), (Subscribe, Client, Update), (Subscribe, Client, Delete), (Subscribe, Client, Drop), (Subscribe, Client, Alter), (Subscribe, Client, Restart), (Subscribe, Client, Error), (Subscribe, Client, Query), (Subscribe, Client, Invalid), (Subscribe, Client, Options), (Subscribe, Client, Isolation), (Subscribe, Client, Expired), (Subscribe, Client, Resource), (Subscribe, Client, PreviousFire), (Subscribe, Client, TemplateLimit), (Subscribe, Client, Merge), (Subscribe, Client, Unknown), (Subscribe, Client, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Data, Truncate), (Unknown, Data, Insert), (Unknown, Data, Update), (Unknown, Data, Delete), (Unknown, Data, Drop), (Unknown, Data, Alter), (Unknown, Data, Restart), (Unknown, Data, Error), (Unknown, Data, Query), (Unknown, Data, Invalid), (Unknown, Data, Options), (Unknown, Data, Isolation), (Unknown, Data, Expired), (Unknown, Data, Resource), (Unknown, Data, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Data, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Data, Merge), (Unknown, Data, Unknown), (Unknown, Data, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Timeout, Truncate), (Unknown, Timeout, Insert), (Unknown, Timeout, Update), (Unknown, Timeout, Delete), (Unknown, Timeout, Drop), (Unknown, Timeout, Alter), (Unknown, Timeout, Restart), (Unknown, Timeout, Error), (Unknown, Timeout, Query), (Unknown, Timeout, Invalid), (Unknown, Timeout, Options), (Unknown, Timeout, Isolation), (Unknown, Timeout, Expired), (Unknown, Timeout, Resource), (Unknown, Timeout, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Timeout, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Timeout, Merge), (Unknown, Timeout, Unknown), (Unknown, Timeout, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Object, Truncate), (Unknown, Object, Insert), (Unknown, Object, Update), (Unknown, Object, Delete), (Unknown, Object, Drop), (Unknown, Object, Alter), (Unknown, Object, Restart), (Unknown, Object, Error), (Unknown, Object, Query), (Unknown, Object, Invalid), (Unknown, Object, Options), (Unknown, Object, Isolation), (Unknown, Object, Expired), (Unknown, Object, Resource), (Unknown, Object, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Object, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Object, Merge), (Unknown, Object, Unknown), (Unknown, Object, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Database, Truncate), (Unknown, Database, Insert), (Unknown, Database, Update), (Unknown, Database, Delete), (Unknown, Database, Drop), (Unknown, Database, Alter), (Unknown, Database, Restart), (Unknown, Database, Error), (Unknown, Database, Query), (Unknown, Database, Invalid), (Unknown, Database, Options), (Unknown, Database, Isolation), (Unknown, Database, Expired), (Unknown, Database, Resource), (Unknown, Database, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Database, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Database, Merge), (Unknown, Database, Unknown), (Unknown, Database, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, System, Truncate), (Unknown, System, Insert), (Unknown, System, Update), (Unknown, System, Delete), (Unknown, System, Drop), (Unknown, System, Alter), (Unknown, System, Restart), (Unknown, System, Error), (Unknown, System, Query), (Unknown, System, Invalid), (Unknown, System, Options), (Unknown, System, Isolation), (Unknown, System, Expired), (Unknown, System, Resource), (Unknown, System, PreviousFire), (Unknown, System, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, System, Merge), (Unknown, System, Unknown), (Unknown, System, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Statement, Truncate), (Unknown, Statement, Insert), (Unknown, Statement, Update), (Unknown, Statement, Delete), (Unknown, Statement, Drop), (Unknown, Statement, Alter), (Unknown, Statement, Restart), (Unknown, Statement, Error), (Unknown, Statement, Query), (Unknown, Statement, Invalid), (Unknown, Statement, Options), (Unknown, Statement, Isolation), (Unknown, Statement, Expired), (Unknown, Statement, Resource), (Unknown, Statement, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Statement, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Statement, Merge), (Unknown, Statement, Unknown), (Unknown, Statement, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Environment, Truncate), (Unknown, Environment, Insert), (Unknown, Environment, Update), (Unknown, Environment, Delete), (Unknown, Environment, Drop), (Unknown, Environment, Alter), (Unknown, Environment, Restart), (Unknown, Environment, Error), (Unknown, Environment, Query), (Unknown, Environment, Invalid), (Unknown, Environment, Options), (Unknown, Environment, Isolation), (Unknown, Environment, Expired), (Unknown, Environment, Resource), (Unknown, Environment, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Environment, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Environment, Merge), (Unknown, Environment, Unknown), (Unknown, Environment, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Execution, Truncate), (Unknown, Execution, Insert), (Unknown, Execution, Update), (Unknown, Execution, Delete), (Unknown, Execution, Drop), (Unknown, Execution, Alter), (Unknown, Execution, Restart), (Unknown, Execution, Error), (Unknown, Execution, Query), (Unknown, Execution, Invalid), (Unknown, Execution, Options), (Unknown, Execution, Isolation), (Unknown, Execution, Expired), (Unknown, Execution, Resource), (Unknown, Execution, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Execution, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Execution, Merge), (Unknown, Execution, Unknown), (Unknown, Execution, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Owner, Truncate), (Unknown, Owner, Insert), (Unknown, Owner, Update), (Unknown, Owner, Delete), (Unknown, Owner, Drop), (Unknown, Owner, Alter), (Unknown, Owner, Restart), (Unknown, Owner, Error), (Unknown, Owner, Query), (Unknown, Owner, Invalid), (Unknown, Owner, Options), (Unknown, Owner, Isolation), (Unknown, Owner, Expired), (Unknown, Owner, Resource), (Unknown, Owner, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Owner, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Owner, Merge), (Unknown, Owner, Unknown), (Unknown, Owner, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Unknown, Truncate), (Unknown, Unknown, Insert), (Unknown, Unknown, Update), (Unknown, Unknown, Delete), (Unknown, Unknown, Drop), (Unknown, Unknown, Alter), (Unknown, Unknown, Restart), (Unknown, Unknown, Error), (Unknown, Unknown, Query), (Unknown, Unknown, Invalid), (Unknown, Unknown, Options), (Unknown, Unknown, Isolation), (Unknown, Unknown, Expired), (Unknown, Unknown, Resource), (Unknown, Unknown, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Unknown, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Unknown, Merge), (Unknown, Unknown, Unknown), (Unknown, Unknown, AlreadyChanged), (Unknown, Client, Truncate), (Unknown, Client, Insert), (Unknown, Client, Update), (Unknown, Client, Delete), (Unknown, Client, Drop), (Unknown, Client, Alter), (Unknown, Client, Restart), (Unknown, Client, Error), (Unknown, Client, Query), (Unknown, Client, Invalid), (Unknown, Client, Options), (Unknown, Client, Isolation), (Unknown, Client, Expired), (Unknown, Client, Resource), (Unknown, Client, PreviousFire), (Unknown, Client, TemplateLimit), (Unknown, Client, Merge), (Unknown, Client, Unknown), (Unknown, Client, AlreadyChanged)
```

Sources: [SqlNotificationType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0fkxc6y(v=vs.90).aspx), [SqlNotificationSource Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationsource(v=vs.90).aspx), [SqlNotificationInfo Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo(v=vs.90).aspx) and [SqlNotificationType.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlNotificationType.cs,2d7b5b4a7f3ea40a), [SqlNotificationInfo.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlNotificationInfo.cs,b211ec691acb89b8), [SqlNotificationSource.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlNotificationSource.cs,57801cb1ead1864d)